# Is there a way to timeout a Postgres commit?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, psycopg2

We have an app that is using psycopg2 to write records to RDS Postgres.  Occasionally when a scale-down event occurs and the container stops during an insert commit, this creates a deadlock on the table.  We are using a threaded connection pool with some standard timeouts as seen below:

```
    self._pool = pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(
        mincount,
        maxcount,
        dsn,
        cursor_factory=cursor_factory,
        application_name=application_name or name,
        keepalives_idle=1,
        keepalives_interval=1,
        keepalives_count=5,
        options=f"-c statement_timeout={statement_timeout}s -c idle_in_transaction_session_timeout={idle_in_transaction_session_timeout}s",
```

The idle in transaction timeout seems to be working as transactions occurring after throw a timeout error rather than waiting silently, but we're still getting lock issues.  Is there a different timeout we should use to have Postgres kill these transactions?

Update on issue:

We have 2 different applications.  One that writes to the table and another that reads from it. We're see this error occasionally pop up in the write application:

```
deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 31504 waits for ShareLock on transaction 33994594; blocked by process 28310.
Process 28310 waits for ShareLock on transaction 33994595; blocked by process 31504.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while inserting
```

Which if I pull the pg_stat_activity for those pids, I get this:

```
[
  {
    "datid": 262668,
    "datname": "app_db",
    "pid": 31504,
    "usename": "app",
    "application_name": "app-Writer",
    "query_start": "2020-10-28 23:16:23.859818",
    "state_change": "2020-10-28 23:16:23.865455",
    "wait_event_type": "Client",
    "wait_event": "ClientRead",
    "state": "idle",
    "backend_xid": null,
    "backend_xmin": null,
    "query": "COMMIT",
    "backend_type": "client backend"
  },
  {
    "datid": 262668,
    "datname": "app_db",
    "pid": 28310,
    "usename": "app",
    "application_name": "app-Writer",
    "query_start": "2020-10-28 23:12:01.232097",
    "state_change": "2020-10-28 23:12:01.234281",
    "wait_event_type": "Client",
    "wait_event": "ClientRead",
    "state": "idle",
    "backend_xid": null,
    "backend_xmin": null,
    "query": "COMMIT",
    "backend_type": "client backend"
  }
]
```

The reader app later fails with this error:

```
psycopg2.InternalError: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

Both the reader and writer apps have the same timeout settings.

Comment: I don't understand. If there is a deadlock in the database, it will be resolved automatically after 1 second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, if the deadlock occurs only rarely, don't worry too much: all you have to do is teach your application to repeat the transaction if it encounters the deadlock. Read on if you need to get rid of the deadlock.

The `COMMIT` you are seeing in `pg_stat_activity` is a red herring: the `query` column contains the last statement that was sent on that connection, and that probably was the `COMMIT` that ended the transaction **after** the deadlock happened.

Readers and writers never block each other in PostgreSQL, so the deadlock must be between two data modifying transactions.

You should do what the error message tells you and consult the PostgreSQL log file. There you find more information, in particular the statements that were being executed when the deadlock happened. This information is not sent to the client because it may contain sensitive data.

To debug the problem, you have to consider **all** the statements that were executed in these transactions, because it may well be that earlier statements in the transaction took locks that contributed to the deadlock. Remember that locks are held until the end of the transaction.

If you cannot identify the transactions and what they did from your application code, you could set `log_statement = 'all'` in PostgreSQL and make sure that the transaction ID (`%x`) is included in `log_prefix`. That will cause all statements to be logged (beware of performance problems), and when the error happens, you can find all the statements that belong to the involved transactions in the log.

This is cumbersome, but the only way if you cannot find the statements from your application end.

Once you know the statements, you can reproduce and debug the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I'm going to look at the logs today.  When you say "Readers and writers never block each other in PostgreSQL", I'm wondering why our reader app is failing with the "terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout"?  This is just a select statement so I'm confused why this would be blocked?

Comment: Ah , that is something entirely different. That transaction is not blocked, it started a transaction, did soethig and then forgot the close the (read only) transaction. Now `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` must be set, and the transaction is canceled.